Regarding banishment and force cage
Suppose you are fighting an enemy and you manage to banish it to a safe demiplane. Next turn you cast forcecage around where the enemy was. When banishment ends, what happens with the enemy? Here are some possibilities:

it returns inside the cage
it returns outside the cage
it fails the charisma saving throw and remains in the demiplane


It returns inside the cage.
Forcecage stops a creature from leaving it by nonmagical means. Entering the cage through magical means or interplanar travel does not require a save at all.
